# Why is the performance gap between array literals and BufferArray so big?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I try to understand about the ArrayBuffer in js as it one of the transferable types between a thread and a worker.

I find huge performance gap into variable creation and I'm unable to find an answer over the internet.

I tried several benchmarking and arrays litterals are always much much more faster to declare than TypedArrays. I tried in node 11, chrome and firefox, results are coherent.

```
var LIMIT = 10000;
console.time("Array insertion time");
for (var i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
    var arr = new Array();
}
console.timeEnd("Array insertion time");


console.time("ArrayBuffer insertion time");
for (var i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(LIMIT * 4);
  var arr = new Int32Array(buffer);
}
console.timeEnd("ArrayBuffer insertion time");
```

I receive crazy results:
Array insertion time: `1.283ms`
ArrayBuffer insertion time: `53.979ms`

I thought it would be faster for JS Engine to declare a TypedArray than a litteral. I thought ArrayBuffer was a very optimized call for allocating memory to the programm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are simply not doing the same thing at all...

When you declare an ArrayBuffer, the browser will ask for a static memory slot, the size of this ArrayBuffer.
An Array on the other hand doesn't have a static memory slot, it will get reassigned while its length will get updated.

So if you want to perform a fair test, then you need to assign some data in these Arrays, because currently, they're just empty objects for what the engine is concerned, i.e they have a very low foot-print, and are very fast to generate.

```js
var LIMIT = 5000; // I have to lower the LIMIT because Array is so slow
console.time("Array insertion time");
for (var i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
  // to be fair, they should hold the same data
  var arr = new Array(LIMIT * 4).fill(0);
}
console.timeEnd("Array insertion time");


console.time("ArrayBuffer insertion time");
for (var i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(LIMIT * 4);
  var arr = new Int32Array(buffer);
}
console.timeEnd("ArrayBuffer insertion time");
```

Comment: @Soviut updated.
The result is really significant. A large win to ArrayBuffer. It was totally counter intuitive for me that an array with specific bounds (so no bounds check) was slower than an array without bounds and bound check. I understand why my test wasn't comparing the same things. Thank you !

Answer (score -2):

Primitive types are generally always going to be faster. They're used so frequently they get the most attention for optimization in the engine. Typed arrays most likely have more overhead because they're performing type checks on operations like inserting. That doesn't come for free.

Additionally, your 2nd example is doing more work declaring the buffer then converting it to a typed array. You're also performing very small operations where ArrayBuffers are intended to store much larger long buffers like binary audio or images.

Comment: “primitive types” might be a bit of a confusing term to use, since JavaScript *has* a class of types called primitives and array isn’t one.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it's for complete different usages

Comment: Correct, it's less about type safety and more about needing to deal with linear data that isn't lossy like an array of floats might be.

Comment: That's just plain wrong. Array are no primitives, ArrayBuffer are way faster than doing the same thing with an Array, case here was just not doing the same thing at all, and finally, TypedArrays are just views over the ArrayBuffer. Generating one takes no significant time whatsoever: https://jsperf.com/typedarray-generation